# Convert parametric to cartesian

Tags: calculus, parametric

could someone help me in this problem? i wanna convert $$x=t\sin t+\cos t,\;\;\;y=\sin t-t\cos t$$
to cartesian, but i'm not finding a way to get rid of t. I tried to square it all and add them up but i got $x^2+y^2=t^2+1$. t is still there. Any tips would be amazing. thanks in advance

Comment: What you have here is a parametric representation of an Archimedean spiral. There is no simple cartesian equation for this spiral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But... you have the solution !

$$t=\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}$$

and

$$x=\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}\sin\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}+\cos\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}$$

is an implicit Cartesian equation.